# I can't map a network drive to sharepoint

Tags: windows, sharepoint, microsoft-office-365, mappeddrive

On a Windows 8 client.

I can browse to my sharepoint site in 365 without issues: https://myPublicserver.sharepoint.com

But when I try to map a drive to that address I get this error:
"The folder you entered does not appear to be valid"

I made sure to add https://myPublicserver.sharepoint.com to my trusted list of sites.

What could the problem be?

Edit: OK I tried to do it with net and this is the error I get:

```
C:\Users\me>net use b: https://mypublicserver.sharepoint.com/my%20lib
System error 224 has occurred.

Access Denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first add the web
 site to your trusted sites list, browse to the web site, and select the option
to login automatically.
```

I can confirm though that the site has been added to the trusted sites list.

Comment: How are you trying to map this?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you can't map a drive letter to a URL, but you can add it as a Network Location. Use the drive mapping tool in File/Windows Explorer and select the option "Connect to a Web site that you can use to store your documents and pictures".

Comment: @joeqwerty, in fact, you can, as long as there's a WebDAV server running behind that URL (i.e. SharePoint) and WebClient service running on the workstation (default for Windows client-OS).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tested this myself on the latest build of Windows 10 and in fact I am seeing the same issue: `NET USE B: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/library` results in *System error 224 has occurred* error out of the box.

Anyhow, I was able to get it working by doing the following:

1. Add **https://*.sharepoint.com** to list of *Trusted Sites*
2. Open https://tenant.sharepoint.com via Internet Explorer and select **Keep me signed in** before entering your credentials
3. As soon as credentials are entered and you are successfully logged in to the site via IE, `NET USE B: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/library` works.

Anyhow, it is likely you might need to do that after every reboot, so that is the reason there are already some community scripts that automate this (i.e. [OneDriveMapper](http://www.lieben.nu/liebensraum/onedrivemapper/)). Windows 10 (not Windows 8) allows mapping your Office 365 account to your local account, so doing that should eliminate the issue as well.

Comment: One KEY point is that you must sign in via Internet Explorer. I first tried Chrome and then Edge but the mapping was not successful until I used IE.

Comment: "select Keep me signed in before entering your credentials" - this isn't appearing for me, at least at the moment.  (This is using IE 11 on Win 10 Pro)

Answer (score 2):

Another way this can be done is with a commercial product called WebDrive (full disclosure: I work for the developer of this product). WebDrive maps a persistent drive letter to SharePoint Servers (and many other cloud services and server types as well).

A huge benefit for system admins is the ability to preconfigure settings and push them out to all of your users. You can download a free trial [here](https://southrivertech.com/products/webdrive/download/).